# Vb.net Read Text from file

Tags: vb.net

i have a text, from text file it's name Lucky.ini

> [Group1]
>   Number = 0811
>   Coupon = 0118
>   [Group2]
>   Number = 4852
>   Coupon = 7112

How to read this text to textbox, but I want to read the number after the "="
and i've two groups.
First, Cheap and
Second, Rich
[image]

Comment: If you cant rewrite/revise how the data is stored (such as serializing, or a CSV), you will have to resort to PInvokes to sort that out.  INI files were never intended to be used as databases.

Answer (score 0):

I used Regex to parse the text file.  See code below

```css
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Data
Public Class Form1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.txt"

    '[Group1]
    'Number = 0811
    'Coupon = 0118
    '[Group2]
    'Number = 4852
    'Coupon = 7112
    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Group", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Number", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("Coupon", GetType(String))

        Dim input As String = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME)
        Dim pattern As String = "[^\[]*\[(?'name'[^\]]+)\]\s*Number\s+=\s*(?'number'\d+)\s*Coupon\s*=\s*(?'coupon'\d+)"
        Dim expr As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)

        Dim matches As MatchCollection = expr.Matches(input)
        For Each m As Match In matches
            Dim name As String = m.Groups("name").Value
            Dim number As String = m.Groups("number").Value
            Dim coupon As String = m.Groups("coupon").Value
            dt.Rows.Add(New String() {name, number, coupon})
        Next m

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        Dim richNumber = dt.Rows(0)("number")
        Dim richCoupon = dt.Rows(0)("coupon")

        Dim cheapNumber = dt.Rows(1)("number")
        Dim cheapCoupon = dt.Rows(1)("coupon")

    End Sub

End Class
​
```